# Difference between position of const in parameters

Tags: c++, parameters, constants

This might have been asked and might be a silly question, but what is the difference between these:

```
void f(int const& par);
void f(const int& par);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference, const is applied to the left unless it comes first, then it applies to the right.